# How do I change pip installation to use python pip

Tags: python, pip

Currently I install `subprocess32` using pip as follows,I want to remove the dependency on pip and use python,How do I change the `pip.main(["install", "subprocess32"])` to `C:\Python27\python.exe -m pip install subprocess32`

```
try:
    import subprocess32
except ImportError:
    pip.main(["install", "subprocess32"])#change this call to C:\Python27\python.exe -m pip install subprocess32
```

Comment: Installing packages in a Python script doesn't seem like a good idea to me.  Why not put your requirements in a text file like "requirements.txt" and use "pip install -r requirements.txt" to install them before you run the script?

Comment: I don't want to use `pip`,"pip install -r requirements.txt" still uses pip..do you have any pointers on how to use execute `C:\Python27\python.exe -m pip install subprocess32` programmatically?

Comment: Well pip is kindly the best practice of Python package management. If you don't want to use pip or add any other dependencies, you had to download and install the [subprocess32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/subprocess32/) manually.

Comment: Btw, in Windows you can use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or [bash for Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/265900/everything-you-can-do-with-windows-10s-new-bash-shell/). It's not that awful to utilize pip.

Comment: @PhilipTzou - am still using pip but as python pip..I just want to remove the dependency where users did not add path to `pip`,please suggest how can I run `C:\Python27\python.exe -m pip install subprocess32` programmatically?

Comment: u mean `os.system("C:\Python27\python.exe -m pip install subprocess32")`?